# Drag an image and dynamically generate text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i have a project where an image has to be dragged and dropped it in a specified area and when i drop it the text box should be generated with label like asp.net tool box. I am able to drag  the image by using jquery but don't have any idea how to get text area. So it will be very helpful if anyone has an idea regarding this.
Thank you,
Vijayesh.

here is what i have tried for dragging and am new to js or jquery

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
       $("#Drag1").draggable( {
         cancel: "a.ui-icon", 
         revert: "invalid", 
         helper: "clone",
            });
      $("#drop").droppable({  });

       </script>
```

Comment: share your code, that you tried for textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you would like to dynamically create elements client side.

I would suggest that you look into [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) in the jQuery API.

Here is a simple example:

```
$('#parent').append('<textarea>SampleText</textarea>');
```

**BETTER EXAMPLE:**

Say I have:

```
<div id="dvStuff">

</div>
```

In jquery I can do:

```
$('#dvStuff').append('<input type="text"></input>');
```

and I would endup with:

```
<div id="dvStuff"> 

<input type="text"></input>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

So using the draggable api you can use the [stop event](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop)

```
stop: function( event, ui ) { $("#Drag1").append('<textarea>SampleText</textarea>');}
```

Comment: yea i want to dynamically create elements on client side. Can you just elaborate it little more as i am new to js.

Comment: its jquery... the append function (and its similar functions in jquery) will create elements as you define them in the DOM where you specify...

Comment: see the examples above.  jQuery is a tool set.  To find an exact fix for your particular issue it is going to require some tinkering.  You're going to have to use the tools to figure out how to make it work for you.